# Android: how to Capture the keyboard dismiss event, not a Back Key

Tags: android, keyboard, hide

Anyway to Capture the keyboard hide event, when clicking on the *Down* key?

I've read many thread in the last two hour but can not find an answer.

The *Down* key shows as the below picture.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give your activity's root view a known ID, say `@+id/activityRoot`, hook a `GlobalLayoutListener` into the `ViewTreeObserver`, and from there calculate the size diff between your activity's view root and the window size:

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
        if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
            ... do something here
        }
     }
});
```

Note: Your application must set this flag in Android Manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` otherwise above solution will not work.

Comment: Is there anyway to listen to the *Down* Key button?

Comment: I don't want to use the adjustResize, since it will change the UI.